About Grothendieck and special cases
I was recently reminded of a quote about (not by!) Alexander Grothendieck that I had read many years ago, I think in the 1990s or 2000s.
The quote was about the way in which Grothendieck solved mathematical problems: that he tried to find a standpoint from which there are no special cases. (Then the actual solution of the problem would be easy.)
Has anyone here encountered this quote? (And is it actually a good characterisation of Grothendieck's style? The answers to this question seem to support a positive answer.)

Maybe you are thinking of Grothendieck's famous analogy about his approach to solving problems being like soaking a nut in water to open it (see e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/The+Rising+Sea).

No, that quote was well-known even to me. :) I could have not mixed up the two quotes.

This is not the remark about looking for categories with complicated objects but good categorical properties in place of categories with simple objects but worse categorical properties, right?

@LSpice since that is the quote in the linked question, I would doubt it.

An idea is discussed in Colin Mclarty's paper "The Rising Sea:
Grothendieck on simplicity and generality I" which could be where your paraphrase of Grothendieck's method originated. That source does give quite a lot of background for this so may be of use to you.

My Mullvad browser refused to visit your link ("something something security ...") but here's one from ncatlab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/McLartyRisingSea.pdf

@David.C.Norris  Thanks

The quote about how Grothendieck solved mathematical problems—emphasizing his approach of finding a standpoint where there are no special cases—is quite general. Without knowing enough about your experience, it’s difficult to provide a precise answer. For instance, I know several quotes related to that topic, but here is one.
During the 1966 celebration of Grothendieck's Fields Medal, Dieudonné remarked (Les travaux de Alexandre Grothendieck):

S'il fallait chercher une parenté spirituelle à Grothendieck, c'est
à Hilbert, me semble-t-il, qu'on pourrait le mieux le comparer :
comme Hilbert, sa devise pourrait être : « simplifier en généralisant »,
en recherchant les ressorts profonds des phénomènes mathématiques ;
mais, comme Hilbert aussi, lorsque cette analyse en profondeur
a conduit à un point où seule l'attaque de front reste possible, il
trouve presque toujours dans sa riche imagination le bélier qui
enfonce l'obstacle. La comparaison est peut-être lourde à porter,
mais Grothendieck est de taille à n'en pas être accablé.

~ (If one had to seek a spiritual kinship for Grothendieck, it seems to me that the best comparison would be with Hilbert: like Hilbert, his motto could be 'simplify by generalizing,' seeking the profound mechanisms behind mathematical phenomena. But, also like Hilbert, when this in-depth analysis leads to a point where only a direct frontal attack remains possible, he almost always finds, in his rich imagination, the battering ram to break through the obstacle. The comparison may be a heavy one to bear, but Grothendieck is well capable of shouldering it without being overwhelmed.)
Hilbert is often credited to said (Quoted in N Rose Mathematical Maxims and Minims (Raleigh N C 1988)):

The art of doing mathematics consists in finding that special case which contains all the germs of generality.

Luckily enough for Grothendieck, the special cases were wisely (and primarily) suggested by Serre! (See their correspondence)

Especially the first paragraph of this answer reads like ChatGPT wrote it. It’s always better to rewrite it into your own words (the tone is quite strange).
